# Create a table for each column in the range

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I'm having trouble on knowing where to start if I want to create multiple tables in a single worksheet.

Requirements
*I have 6 columns and each column needs to be it's own table
*Each column can have a different number of values in it so I need to include a clause for usedRange in each column. As this can vary each time the worksheet is created

I tried the recorder and because I manually selected the range for each column, it's not what I'm looking for since the number of rows in the usedRange will be different for each worksheet

Here's the recorded script mentioned above:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Add a new table at range A1:A2 on selectedSheet
let newTable = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A2"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable
newTable.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable to "Sample1"
newTable.setName("Sample1");
// Add a new table at range B1:B2 on selectedSheet
let newTable_1 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("B1:B2"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable_1
newTable_1.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable_1 to "Sample2"
newTable_1.setName("Sample2");
// Add a new table at range C1:C3 on selectedSheet
let newTable_2 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("C1:C3"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable_2
newTable_2.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable_2 to "Sample3"
newTable_2.setName("Sample3");
// Add a new table at range D1:D5 on selectedSheet
let newTable_3 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("D1:D5"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable_3
newTable_3.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable_3 to "Sample4"
newTable_3.setName("Sample4");
// Add a new table at range E1:E5 on selectedSheet
let newTable_4 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("E1:E5"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable_4
newTable_4.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable_4 to "Sample5"
newTable_4.setName("Sample5");
// Add a new table at range F1:F3 on selectedSheet
let newTable_5 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("F1:F3"), true);
// Change the visibility of banded rows on table newTable_5
newTable_5.setShowBandedRows(false);
// Rename table newTable_5 to "Sample6"
newTable_5.setName("Sample6");
```

}

Comment: So create a variable. Edit: I don't use office scripts but I imagine is 2 lines of code. One to declare variable and another to set it to last row.

Comment: I’m unclear, can you show us an example of what you’re basing the script off?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on why each column needs to be its own table rather than have all of the columns in one table?

Comment: Thank You- I was able to solve this by finding a solution on-line. Here's a snippet of how I reference specific columns                                                                                  
  let InvoiceNumberusedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getColumn(0);
  let InvoiceNumbercolumn = InvoiceNumberusedRange.getColumn(0).select();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the whole column as a range, and then use the getUsedRange() method. Example code -

```
    let table3 = workbook.addTable(selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").getUsedRange(), true);
```